# Get every possible combination of product related tags

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The database structure is like this:
[image]

The Tags table looks something like this:

```
 ID      NAME
 ----------------------
 1       Blue
 2       Green
 3       Small
 4       Large
 5       Red
```

They would be related to products through the ProductTag table.

What I'm trying to return is every single combination of tags related to a product, like this:

```
 IDs      TAGS
 ----------------------
 1       Blue
 2       Green
 1,3     Small, Blue
 2,3     Small, Green
 1,4     Large, Blue
 2,4     Large, Green
 3       Small
 4       Large
 5       Red
```

(Every single one of these combinations has products)

I think SQL 2005 has something called `WITH CUBE` to help accomplish something like this, but unfortunately this doesn't seem to work in SQL 2008. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Every 1 and 2 combination?  What about the combination Blue, Red.  I don't see anything in your table that denotes what type of attribute it is, so nothing in SQL will say "this is a color; that is a size; only allow one of each".

Comment: The ProductTag table, the relationship of each product to x number of tags, should be used to produce the list of combinations

Comment: Ah I see what you want now.  So it's only every combination that has products and NOT every valid combination of tags?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this must help you.

```
;WITH TagsCTE
AS
(
   SELECT P.ProductID, T.ID,T.Name
   FROM ProductTags P
     JOIN Tag T
       ON P.TagID = T.ID
)
SELECT
   STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(ID as varchar) FROM TagsCTE TC WHERE TC.ProductID = TT.ProductID FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') IDs, 
   STUFF((SELECT ',' + Name FROM TagsCTE TC WHERE TC.ProductID = TT.ProductID FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') Tags
FROM TagsCTE TT
GROUP BY ProductID
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c09d8/7)**

Comment: This only gets `Blue,Small,Large`, how do you get them in other orders as well?  Like `Small,Large,Blue`, `Blue,Large,Small`, etc..

Comment: Not clear. Do  you want shuffle them? Try add `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Yes I want to shuffle them like a data cube